# Hello, I need add percentage to script bellow, tks

Tags: batch-file

```
    @echo.
    @echo ######## COPIA DOS ARQUIVOS DA PASTA AGENDADOR ########
    @echo.
    Echo AGENDADOR >> F:\Log_Teste_Restaure.log
    Echo %date% %time% - ArcServer1 - Backup - Iniciando copia dos arquivos do AGENDADOR >>         F:\Log_Teste_Restaure.log


    @Echo off
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "source=F:\Backup\Agendador"
    set "target=F:\TESTE_RESTAURE"

    PushD "%source%"
    set "counter=0"
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('dir "Agendador*" /z /b /o:-d /t:w') do (
    set /a counter+=1
    Set Copy[!counter!]=copy "%%~fA" "%target%\"
    if !counter! equ 3 goto :break
    )
    :break
    For /L %%C in (1,1,%counter%) Do !Copy[%%C]!
    PopD
    @Echo %date% %time% * AGENDADOR copiado para a pasta de teste de backup >>         F:\Log_Teste_Restaure.log

    Echo %date% %time% - ArcServer1 - Backup - Finalizando copia dos arquivos do AGENDADOR >>         F:\Log_Teste_Restaure.log
    Echo. >> F:\Log_Teste_Restaure.log
```

Comment: And don't spam with unrelated tags. The code you show is neither Bash nor PowerShell code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this should work:

```
@echo.
@echo ######## COPIA DOS ARQUIVOS DA PASTA AGENDADOR ########
@echo.

Echo AGENDADOR >> F:\Log_Teste_Restaure.log

Echo %date% %time% - ArcServer1 - Backup - Iniciando copia dos arquivos do AGENDADOR >> F:\Log_Teste_Restaure.log

@Echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "source=F:\Backup\Agendador"
set "target=F:\TESTE_RESTAURE"

PushD "%source%"
set "counter=0"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('dir "Agendador*" /z /b /o:-d /t:w') do (
    set /a counter+=1
    Set Copy[!counter!]=copy "%%~fA" "%target%\"
    if !counter! equ 3 goto :break
)


:break
For /L %%C in (1,1,%counter%) Do ( 
    !Copy[%%C]!  
    Echo > %temp%\Progess_agendador.vbs Wscript.Echo "Progress....." ^& FormatNumber((%%C/!counter!)*100,2) ^& "%" 
    cscript /nologo %temp%\Progess_agendador.vbs)
PopD
@Echo %date% %time% * AGENDADOR copiado para a pasta de teste de backup >> F:\Log_Teste_Restaure.log

Echo %date% %time% - ArcServer1 - Backup - Finalizando copia dos arquivos do AGENDADOR >> F:\Log_Teste_Restaure.log
Echo. >> F:\Log_Teste_Restaure.log
```

Comment: `Echo > %temp%\Progess_agendador.vbs Wscript.Echo "Progress....." ^& FormatNumber((!counter!/%%C^)*100,2^) ^& "%%"`

Comment: You're welcome. Although you should check your math...

Comment: @Stephan Ops (Face palm). Thanks again!

Comment: thanks. answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
For /L %%C in (1,1,%counter%) Do !Copy[%%C]!
```

to

```
For /L %%C in (1,1,%counter%) Do (
  set /a percent=%%C*100/counter
  !Copy[%%C]!
  echo !percent! %%
)
```